# ubuntu unable to resolve host

Tags: 14.04, permissions, dpkg, sudo, hosts

I'm working on ubuntu 14.04. I cant login to my pc as a root user.I tried different ways and i cant still the issue.

If i give sudo command the response is like

```
> ubuntu@ubuntu72:~$ sudo su
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu72
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
```

Then i tried the command to get host details `nano /etc/hosts`the response is

```
*127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-Invalid-entry-length-0-DMI-table-is-broken-Stop

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters




                [ Read 9 lines (Warning: No write permission) ]
^G Get Help  ^O WriteOut  ^R Read File ^Y Prev Page ^K Cut Text  ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^J Justify   ^W Where Is  ^V Next Page ^U UnCut Text^T To Spell
*
```

I need to edit this line to solve this issue , i'm unable to edit this line

```
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-Invalid-entry-length-0-DMI-table-is-broken-Stop
```

How can i edit this line  how can i edit i tried this ways.

->1

```
   `ubuntu@ubuntu72:~$ sudo -i gedit /etc/hosts
    sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu72
    [sudo] password for ubuntu:
```

->2

```
ubuntu@ubuntu72:~$ chattr -i /etc/hosts
chattr: Permission denied while setting flags on /etc/hosts
```

->3

By command gedit /etc/hosts i'm able to open the hosts file .I cant change permissions

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu72:/$ chmod 777 -R /etc/hosts
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/etc/hosts’: Operation not permitted
```

`How can i edit this /etc/hosts to fix this issue?
Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: What does `hostname` say?  For some reason your shell thinks your hostname is ubuntu72, but /etc/hosts thinks it is ubuntu-Invalid-entry-length-0-DMI-table-is-broken-Stop.  Did you recently change the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

just edit your `/etc/hosts`, and add

```
127.0.0.1 ubuntu72
```

saved and change permissions

```
sudo chmod 644 hosts
```

and change your owned

```
sudo chown root:root -R host
```

restart with type `sudo init 6`

Hope this helps.

Comment: the command chmod  & chown is not working here i mentioned that in the question.  Is there any other way?

Comment: use with type sudo

Comment: f i give sudo command the response is like

> ubuntu@ubuntu72:~$ sudo su
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu72
[sudo] password for ubuntu:

Comment: you still have hosts issue, follow my answered updated

Comment: All you mentioned in your answer i already tried, it wont work. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: what the output of `ls -l | grep hosts`

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu72:/etc$ ls -l | grep hosts
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root      4096 Jul 23  2014 ghostscript
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       269 Jun 28  2016 hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       411 Jul 23  2014 hosts.allow
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       711 Jul 23  2014 hosts.deny

Comment: all right restart you OS, and try again `sudo su`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Ubuntu DVD or Stick (same or newer release) to start an independet system. Then it should be possible to edit the files like /etc/hosts. Unfortunately this does not resolve the cause of this strange issue. 
Do not miss to e2fsck the partitions when started from CD/DVD/stick. 
The system or the GUI may store the host name in etc in files named(!)  hosts, hosts.conf, host or hostname. When started from CD try to find them all ("sudo ls -latr host*" should do it, otherwise use find.